# Dependency convergence error for org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.2

Tags: maven, ant

When I am trying to build an application I am getting following error since I am new to maven I am not completely aware of what is going wrong that is resulting in build failure.

Following is the log message printed for build failure:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.2 paths to dependency are:
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.2
      +-org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.2
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-abcd:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213740-11
    +-org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.9.4
,
Dependency convergence error for com.google.guava:guava:r09 paths to dependency are:
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations:ehcache-spring-annotations:1.2.0
      +-com.google.guava:guava:r09
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-com.google.guava:guava:18.0
,
Dependency convergence error for org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.3 paths to dependency are:
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.owasp.esapi:esapi:2.1.0.1
      +-org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.3
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.8
,
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4 paths to dependency are:
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5
,
Dependency convergence error for xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03 paths to dependency are:
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-com.io7m.xom:xom:1.2.10
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04
and
+-com.srik.prjt.all:abcd:1.1.0-10.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.srik.prjt.src:cug-core:9.5.0-10.0.0-20190918.213714-17
    +-xalan:xalan:2.7.0
      +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.163 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-19T15:40:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-dependency-convergence) on project abcd: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Kindly let me know if any additional details are required.

Ant Version Used: apache-ant-1.10.3

Maven Version used : apache-maven-3.2.1

Edit Performed on Child Pom where build is failing:

between dependency management tag is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.srik.prjt.src</groupId>
    <artifactId>cug-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>${framework.scope}</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.srik.prjt.src</groupId>
    <artifactId>cug-abcd</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (or your parent POM) activated the dependeny convergence enforcer rule. This rule fails the build if you have different versions of the same artifact in your transitive dependency tree.

Either deactivate the enforcer rule or fix the convergence issues by adding appropriate entries to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM (for the artifacts with diverging entries).

Comment: If I try to change Denforce.skip=tru it is throwing [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".skip=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format error

Comment: So can you show me how can I add exclusions in my pom.xml under which tag with an example

Comment: Do you want to skip the enforcer rules? Then you need to add `-Denforcer.skip=true` to your command line call. If you want to fix the problems, you need to add entries for the different problematic dependencies (like `org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:1.5.8`) to your `<dependencyMangement>` section of the POM.

Comment: Do I need to add this in Child or parent Pom . I have added some think like this as mentioned in edits above

Comment: it worked was doing a mistake of repeating so not able to address it thank you.

Comment: You can work with exclusions, but `<dependencyManagement>` is more recommended.

Comment: Yes Got it as it might end me up loosing jars hence adding dependency might end up in adding jars also.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your last sentence. With dependencyManagement, you do not add jars, you just change version numbers.

Comment: okay got it.It is specifying the version of jar to be used in child project right?

Comment: It is overwriting the version of the transitive dependency.